Where to put new TeX classes in Slackware Linux?
I've just downloaded some interesting TeX classes from CTAN website, but I'm not sure where to put these classes in order to make them recognized by my TeX software. I'm using Slackware 15.0.

Welcome! this isn't a good idea. it would be better to install what you want using your package manager, if that's how you installed TeX. if you want things not available from your distro, install vanilla TeX Live from upstream instead. otherwise you're very likely to hit incompatibilities of various kinds.

I see what you mean, @cfr. It happens that my distribution doesn't have all the classes I need. I'll try your other suggestion and install vanilla TeX Live. Thanks for your help.

hmm. most linux distros package all of TeX Live or everything which meets their licence requirements, which is almost the same thing these days (because karl doesn't accept stuff which doesn't meet e.g. debian criteria). so possibly slackware is unusual, but more likely either (1) there are other texlive packages providing the stuff you're missing (since distros typically split TL up into smaller packages) and/or (2) the classes you're missing are recent and your distro packages an old TL. both of these are highly possible. but vanilla would be my preferred option anyway.

if you install vanilla, you probably want to look for a dummy package to keep slackware's package management happy. alternatively, you can keep both installed but need to be aware of which paths software uses when it searches for the binaries.

I removed Slacware packages and installed it full in my user area. This way I avoided conflicts and also acquired a much easier to mana instalation. Using it right now. Thanks once more for your helo, @cfr.

I prefer installing into /usr/local, but that's just my preference. If you don't install a dummy package, the slackware packages won't stay uninstalled unless you don't install anything which depends on TeX. typically, people at least want an editor or some editor plugin for a more generic editor and these will draw in your distro's packages. a dummy prevents this by telling your package manager (falsely) that it provides everything required. so, if you don't want both installed, you probably want to install a dummy to block those installations.
